# Can't go to other activity from fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I've been doing this for some time and I couldn't make this work. I'm using fragment to link to other activity (aforapple) with intent by clicking a button and it crashes. Here is the code. Any solution? Your help is much appreciated.

```
public class PagesFragment extends Fragment {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);

   Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.send);
   mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i= new Intent("aforapple");
          startActivity(i);
      }
   });
   return rootView;
}
```

Comment: post logcat exception and manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
   Intent i= new Intent(getActivity(),aforapple.class);
   getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

Make sure you have `aforapple` activity register in your `manifest.xml`

And for more information go to [Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity)

Comment: +1, thanks!!!! I didn't register in my manifest.xml, thank you so much for reminding, I was stuck for some time..

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
       Intent i= new Intent(getActivity(),aforapple.class);
      getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), aforapple.class);
startActivity(intent);
```